# How can I go from month view to day view using RadCalendar?

Tags: c#, xamarin, telerik

I'm using a calendar (RadCalendar from Telerik) and I want, from a month view, go to a day view when I click on a specific day. How can I do that ?

Comment: I do not think Telerik has this feature you might have to create your own version of that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use the `SelectedDate` binding or `SelectionChanged` event. When either of these occurs set the `ViewMode` of the calendar to `Day`. There are some issues with day mode tracking a different `SelectedDate` than month mode, but they are working on a fix for that.